# how to increment to the next variable?

Tags: java, variables, arraylist

I am writing a program that takes in a CSV file and makes a table out of the content from it. Then I apply a filter that will eliminate the bad entries in it, and I want to store those into a different ArrayList using the .add(originalTable())

The problem I am having is I want to apply different filters and get different ArrayList each with the incremented number. So the OriginalTable is filter0 than filter1 than filter2. The problem I am running into is how do I increment the number of Filter over one ?

```
       State Population Death
       1     10000      10
       2     10001      10
       3     10002      0
       4     1200       100
       5     1          900
       6     1213       900
```

Okay so I have data like this in my Table which is just an arrayList of ArrayList, ArrayList one being the rows stored into the columns. Now let say I apply the filter that I want deaths less than or equal to 10 deaths and this should give me another "table" called filter which will give me:

```
       State Population Death
       1     10000      10
       2     10001      10
       3     10002      0
```

This will be called filter1 now I apply another filter to this saying let me have only only with population bigger than 10,000 population and this is will result in another "table" called filter2. 
Which would look something like this:

```
       State Population Death
       2     10001      10
       3     10002      0
```

I don't know how to increment it from filter0 to filter1 to filter2  and they have to be arrayList of ArrayList each time. Thank you guys so much! :)

```
      else if (task.contentEquals("filter")){
            String filter = keyboard.nextLine(); 
            String[] filterArray = filter.split(" ");
            int colmn = 0;
            String predicate ;
            String Value = "W";
            if(filter.contains("-v ")){
            // do the seperate cutoff strings   System.out.println("yeah it contains v");
            }else{
                colmn = Integer.parseInt(filterArray[1]);
                predicate = filterArray[2];
                //Value = filterArray[3];
                System.out.println(colmn +" "+ predicate + " "+Value);
            }
            for(int i =0; i <table.size(); i++){
                if(table.get(i).get(colmn).toString().contains(Value)){
                    filterTable.add(table.get(i));
                    System.out.println(table.get(i));
                }
            }
```

Comment: could you please post some code to elaborate your problem a bit further?

Comment: filter [-v <viewnumber>] <column-num> ( < | <= | = | >= | >) <value>
This produces a new table view which includes only the which satisfy the specied predicate on the specied column. The newly created view is assigned the next available view number and this number is reported to the user (assuming the command does not fail).

Comment: What kind of "table"? What kind of filter? What library(ies?) are you using? What context?

Comment: tabe is an array list of Arraylist which looks like how your excel program looks like.

Comment: @Ashley: You're not helping here. You're assuming a lot of context that nobody shares with you.  If you don't post your code (by editing the original post, not in a comment) there is no way anybody can help you.  We can't read your mind.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I added a more detailed explanation. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explore the guava library. The library isn't huge and provides several ways to solve such problems using oops principles; will help you maintain good object structure.

Comment: I am able to even filter them but I keep over writing the pervious filter I just to get it somehow increment it. Is there anyway I can add it to a array list becoz it would increment each time ?

Comment: Over write seems to suggest that you keep writing on the same reference; your filters should be returning a new copy of the list to avoid being over written. Show us your code, specifically the problem and we might be able to help.